# Let $A = \{ 1 ,2,..n \} ,B = \{ 1 ,2 , ., m\}$ where $m$ is even. How many functions are there whose range contains only even number?

Tags: functions

I know that the number of functions in total in $m^n$, but how do I find the number of functions that have domain $A$ and Codomain $B$ whose range contains only even number?

Comment: How many values for $1$ are possible?  How many for $2$?  And so on.

Comment: So $f$ takes values in $\{2,4,\ldots,m\}$?

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to the number of functions from $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $C=\{2,4,\ldots,m\}$ i.e $(m/2)^n$.